# Highlighting issue with solr 8.2

Tags: solr, solr-highlight

Partial highlighting for `solr 8.2` is not working fine for me. I am able to do a partial search by using `NGramTokenizerFactory`. But the highlight dosen't seems to be working now.

Here is Field type defination:

```
 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" maxGramSize="15" minGramSize="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Here is my Field:

```
<field name="title" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Query:

```
http://10.232.208.141:8986/solr/up1/select?df=title&hl.fl=title%2Ccontent &hl.simple.post=%3C%2Fb%3E&hl.simple.pre=%3Cb%3E&hl=on&q=digi&rows=1
```

Expected highlight:

```
"title":["AgencyPortal <b>Digi</b>tal Engagement Solution Integration—Case Study | Cognizant"]}},
```

Current output Highlight:

```
"title":["AgencyPortal Digital Engagement Solution Integration—Case Study | Cognizant"]}},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"` attributes to your field.

Your field will look like.

```
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="true"  termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>
```

Try by adding the the below to the query.

```
&hl.q="queryTerm"&hl.usePhraseHighlighter=true&hl.useFastVectorHighlighter=true
```

Here is the Documentation in detail for the Highlighting..
[Solr Highlighting Page](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/highlighting.html)